# Ubuntu 12.04 wired ethernet not working and wireless not working, How do I fix it?

Tags: 12.04, internet, broadcom, ethernet

I am new to ubuntu. I recently installed the latest ubuntu for desktop from http://www.ubuntu.com/download. I was very excited to start using ubuntu until I booted the computer and saw that i couldn't connect to the internet at all.

I have spent hours trying to figure this out. I keep running into people suggesting installing drivers etc. I have tried about everything and nothing seems to work.

I have the ethernet cable connected to the computer but it doesn't recognize it. I ran the following:

```
lspci | grep -i eth
```

and I get this

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5752 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am kind of bummed I have spent all this time tyring to get the internet to work and haven't even gotten to use the power of ubuntu

---

**Update copied from comment:**

Changing the Ethernet cable to a different one fixed the problem.

Comment: That awkward feeling when you change the Ethernet cable to a different one to make sure the one you were using worked....and you find out the cable you were using wasn't working...sigh...

now to figure out why the wireless connection isn't working..:)

Comment: If you have solved your problem you should answer your own question and then "check" the answer as "best". Answering your own question to complete it is perfectly acceptable, even encouraged (if a better answer is not available). See Jeff Atwood's [se] BLOG 01 July 2011 [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions) or the end of this [faq#question] section.

Comment: I would add a new question about the wireless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add IP address in wired Internet settings.